# TypeScript import requires .js extension, but only for some files

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, file-extension

I have `main.ts` file which looks like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment'; // <-- This is the issue
import { AppModule }             from './xxcv/app.module.3';

if (environment.production)
{
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Content of the `environment.ts` is:

```
export const environment = {
    production: true
};
```

All of the imported files exist as .ts files and after they are trans-piled into .js, browser reports error notifying that it cannot find `http://<url>/enviroments/enviroment`.

Everything is in the document root, `environments` and `xxcv`.

When I add `.js` extension explicitly it works. So line looks like this now:

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment.js';
```

Why does this line for example, works without having to specify extension?

```
import { AppModule }             from './xxcv/app.module.3';
```

And this one does not?

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
```

Comment: Just checking a simple mistake, are you sure the file and directory have the same case as specified in your import statement? (i.e. uppercase vs lowercase letters)

Comment: Yes. Like I said when I just add .js at the end it works.

Comment: You could try switching the module resolution method to see if that has any effect. Use the --moduleResolution flag  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node

Comment: FYI, your question says the file ends in '.js' in the second half of the question, which is a bit confusing. Even the title has .js

Comment: All files are in .ts. After transpiling them with tsc each .ts file has its own .js equivalent.

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that about ts. Welp, good luck with this.

Comment: Hi. Can you specify what is the module loader you are using on the browser and what is the "module" configuration on your .tsconfig?

If you use module as System, you need to setup SystemJS to, by default, use the .js extension. https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md

Comment: Those two entries look like this: "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",